# AutoMapper with EF6 not populating one of the mapped objects

Tags: entity-framework, automapper, dto

I have an EF6 MVC app using Code First to generate the models.  I am trying to create a mapping using AutoMapper between the model and a viewmodel representation of that model.

I don't have errors, but the resulting object is missing details for the PTCredential object. Specifically I am missing the PTCredential object that is nested within a PTCredential. 
I don't believe the Ignores are causing this, but I can't pin it down. I have tried some suggestions from other posts on AutoMapper, but nothing has proven useful.

Could anyone provide some assistance on what I can do to successfully use AutoMapper in this situation?

Here is the code for how I am configuring and initializing the Mapper:

```
    var pTConnections = _db.PTConnections.Include(p => p.PTConnectionClass).ToList();

        Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.CreateMap<PTConnection, PTConnectionViewModel>()
                .AfterMap((s, d) => { foreach (var i in d.PTCredentialAssignments) i.PTConnection = d; });

            cfg.CreateMap<PTCredentialAssignment, PTCredentialAssignmentViewModel>()
                .ForMember(m => m.PTCredential, opt => opt.Ignore())
                .ForMember(m => m.PTConnection, opt => opt.Ignore());

            cfg.CreateMap<PTVendor, PTVendorViewModel>()
                .ForMember(m => m.PTCredentials, opt => opt.Ignore())
                .ForMember(m => m.PTConnections, opt => opt.Ignore());

            cfg.CreateMap<PTCredential, PTCredentialViewModel>();

            cfg.CreateMap<PTConnectionClass, PTConnectionClassViewModel>()
                .ForMember(m => m.PTConnections, opt => opt.Ignore());

            cfg.CreateMap<PTConnectionContactAssignment, PTConnectionContactAssignmentViewModel>()
                .ForMember(m => m.PTConnection, opt => opt.Ignore());

        });

    var dest = Mapper.Map<List<PTConnection>, List<PTConnectionViewModel>>(pTConnections);
```

Here is my Code First Model:

```
public partial class PTConnection
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public PTConnection()
    {
        PTConnectionAssignments = new HashSet<PTConnectionAssignment>();
        PTCredentialAssignments = new HashSet<PTCredentialAssignment>();
        PTConnectionContactAssignments = new HashSet<PTConnectionContactAssignment>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int PTCID { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "datetime2")]
    public DateTime ModifiedDate { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(500)]
    public string ModifiedBy { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(255)]
    public string ConnectionName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100)]
    public string Host { get; set; }

    public int Port { get; set; }

    public string Comment { get; set; }

    public int PTCCID { get; set; }

    public bool? IsDisabled { get; set; }

    public int PTVID { get; set; }

    public virtual PTConnectionClass PTConnectionClass { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<PTConnectionAssignment> PTConnectionAssignments { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<PTCredentialAssignment> PTCredentialAssignments { get; set; }

    public virtual PTVendor PTVendor { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<PTConnectionContactAssignment> PTConnectionContactAssignments { get; set; }
}

public partial class PTCredential
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public PTCredential()
    {
        PTCredentialAssignments = new HashSet<PTCredentialAssignment>();
        PTCredentialContactAssignments = new HashSet<PTCredentialContactAssignment>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int PTCRID { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "datetime2")]
    public DateTime ModifiedDate { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(500)]
    public string ModifiedBy { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100)]
    public string CredUsername { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(500)]
    public string CredPassword { get; set; }

    public string Directory { get; set; }

    public bool? IsDisabled { get; set; }

    public string Comments { get; set; }

    public int? PTVID { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<PTCredentialAssignment> PTCredentialAssignments { get; set; }

    public virtual PTVendor PTVendor { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<PTCredentialContactAssignment> PTCredentialContactAssignments { get; set; }
}

public partial class PTVendor
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public PTVendor()
    {
        PTConnections = new HashSet<PTConnection>();
        PTCredentials = new HashSet<PTCredential>();
        PTIneligableCredentialVendorAssignments = new HashSet<PTIneligableCredentialVendorAssignment>();
        PTVendorAssignments = new HashSet<PTVendorAssignment>();
        PTVendorContactAssignments = new HashSet<PTVendorContactAssignment>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int PTVID { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "datetime2")]
    public DateTime ModifiedDate { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(500)]
    public string ModifiedBy { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50), Display(Name="Vendor Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<PTConnection> PTConnections { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<PTCredential> PTCredentials { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<PTIneligableCredentialVendorAssignment> PTIneligableCredentialVendorAssignments { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<PTVendorAssignment> PTVendorAssignments { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<PTVendorContactAssignment> PTVendorContactAssignments { get; set; }
}

[Table("PTCredentialAssignment")]
public partial class PTCredentialAssignment
{
    [Key]
    public int PTCRAID { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "datetime2")]
    public DateTime ModifiedDate { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(500)]
    public string ModifiedBy { get; set; }

    public int PTCID { get; set; }

    public int PTCRID { get; set; }

    public virtual PTConnection PTConnection { get; set; }

    public virtual PTCredential PTCredential { get; set; }
}

[Table("PTConnectionClass")]
public partial class PTConnectionClass
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public PTConnectionClass()
    {
        PTConnections = new HashSet<PTConnection>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int PTCCID { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "datetime2")]
    public DateTime ModifiedDate { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(500)]
    public string ModifiedBy { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Class { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<PTConnection> PTConnections { get; set; }
}

[Table("PTConnectionContactAssignment")]
public partial class PTConnectionContactAssignment
{
    [Key]
    public int PTCCAID { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "datetime2")]
    public DateTime ModifiedDate { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(500)]
    public string ModifiedBy { get; set; }

    public int PTCID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(60)]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(60)]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(10)]
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }

    [StringLength(20)]
    public string Extension { get; set; }

    [StringLength(100)]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [StringLength(60)]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public string Comment { get; set; }

    public virtual PTConnection PTConnection { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my ViewModel:

```
   public partial class PTConnectionViewModel
    {
        [Key]
        public int PTCID { get; set; }

        [Column(TypeName = "datetime2")]
        public DateTime ModifiedDate { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(500)]
        public string ModifiedBy { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(255)]
        public string ConnectionName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(100)]
        public string Host { get; set; }

        public int Port { get; set; }

        public string Comment { get; set; }

        public int PTCCID { get; set; }

        public bool? IsDisabled { get; set; }

        public int PTVID { get; set; }

        public virtual PTConnectionClassViewModel PTConnectionClass { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<PTConnectionAssignmentViewModel> PTConnectionAssignments { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<PTCredentialAssignmentViewModel> PTCredentialAssignments { get; set; }

        public virtual PTVendorViewModel PTVendor { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<PTConnectionContactAssignmentViewModel> PTConnectionContactAssignments { get; set; }
    }

public partial class PTVendorViewModel
{
    [Key]
    public int PTVID { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "datetime2")]
    public DateTime ModifiedDate { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(500)]
    public string ModifiedBy { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50), Display(Name="Vendor Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<PTConnectionViewModel> PTConnections { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<PTCredentialViewModel> PTCredentials { get; set; }

}

public partial class PTCredentialViewModel
{
    [Key]
    public int PTCRID { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "datetime2")]
    public DateTime ModifiedDate { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(500)]
    public string ModifiedBy { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100)]
    public string CredUsername { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(500)]
    public string CredPassword { get; set; }

    public string Directory { get; set; }

    public bool? IsDisabled { get; set; }

    public string Comments { get; set; }

    public int? PTVID { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<PTCredentialAssignmentViewModel> PTCredentialAssignments { get; set; }

    public virtual PTVendorViewModel PTVendor { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<PTCredentialContactAssignmentViewModel> PTCredentialContactAssignments { get; set; }
}

public partial class PTCredentialAssignmentViewModel
{
    [Key]
    public int PTCRAID { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "datetime2")]
    public DateTime ModifiedDate { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(500)]
    public string ModifiedBy { get; set; }

    public int PTCID { get; set; }

    public int PTCRID { get; set; }

    public virtual PTConnectionViewModel PTConnection { get; set; }

    public virtual PTCredentialViewModel PTCredential { get; set; }
}

public partial class PTConnectionClassViewModel
{

    [Key]
    public int PTCCID { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "datetime2")]
    public DateTime ModifiedDate { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(500)]
    public string ModifiedBy { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Class { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<PTConnectionViewModel> PTConnections { get; set; }
}

public partial class PTConnectionContactAssignmentViewModel
{
    [Key]
    public int PTCCAID { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "datetime2")]
    public DateTime ModifiedDate { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(500)]
    public string ModifiedBy { get; set; }

    public int PTCID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(60)]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(60)]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(10)]
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }

    [StringLength(20)]
    public string Extension { get; set; }

    [StringLength(100)]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [StringLength(60)]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public string Comment { get; set; }

    public virtual PTConnectionViewModel PTConnection { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with automapper... however, where do you include the navigation property? with normal DbSet calls this property should be null until enumerated or the corresponding entity is already in the context.

Comment: "Specifically I am missing the PTCredential object that is nested within a PTCredential" -- is that a typo? If you are missing it from PTCredentialAssignmentViewModel then yes, you are telling it to ignore that.

Comment: @Steve-Greene Thanks for your suggestion, sometimes you can't see the forest through the trees, and that's what happened here.  I thought I had gone through my data model so well before I posted but, when you pointed out my typo I went back through and was able to see what I was missing.  I noticed that one of my other objects was mapping was keeping me from doing the correct mapping and getting the right object.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the mapping that made my solution work:

```
       cfg.CreateMap<PTConnection, PTConnectionViewModel>()
            .AfterMap((s, d) => { foreach (var i in d.PTCredentialAssignments) i.PTConnection = d; });

        cfg.CreateMap<PTCredentialAssignment, PTCredentialAssignmentViewModel>()
            .ForMember(m => m.PTConnection, opt => opt.Ignore());

        cfg.CreateMap<PTVendor, PTVendorViewModel>()
            .ForMember(m => m.PTCredentials, opt => opt.Ignore())
            .ForMember(m => m.PTConnections, opt => opt.Ignore());

        cfg.CreateMap<PTCredential, PTCredentialViewModel>()
            .ForMember(m => m.PTCredentialAssignments, opt => opt.Ignore())
            .ForMember(m => m.PTCredentialContactAssignments, opt => opt.Ignore());

        cfg.CreateMap<PTConnectionClass, PTConnectionClassViewModel>()
            .ForMember(m => m.PTConnections, opt => opt.Ignore());

        cfg.CreateMap<PTConnectionContactAssignment, PTConnectionContactAssignmentViewModel>()
            .ForMember(m => m.PTConnection, opt => opt.Ignore());
```